# Google Maps inside Android Webview is not Loading

Tags: java, android, google-maps, webview, android-webview

I have a React Web Application that has a camera and google maps embedded in it. I have hosted this in Netlify and have a link for it.

I'm implementing Android Webviews with the above link in java. I got the camera working but the map isn't loading.

I tried all the ways and saw many StackOverflow questions and I implemented the same but was still not able to load google maps.

Below is the `MainActivity.java` code

```
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    public WebView webView;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
//            if(url.contains("maps"))
//            {
//                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
//                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
//                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
//                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
//                    startActivity(mapIntent);
//                }
//                return true;
//            }
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkMyPermission();


//        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
//        String[] PERMISSIONS = {
//                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
//                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
//                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
//                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
//        };

//        if( !hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS) )
//        {
//            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
//        }

        ActivityResultLauncher<String> cameraPermission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                if(result)
                {
                   System.out.println("GRANTED");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("NOPE");
                }
            }
        });

         cameraPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);


        ActivityResultLauncher<String> Access_Coarse_location_Permission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                if(result)
                {
                    System.out.println("GRANTED");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("NOPE");
                }
            }
        });

        Access_Coarse_location_Permission.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        ActivityResultLauncher<String> Access_Fine_location_Permission = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                if(result)
                {
                    System.out.println("GRANTED");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("NOPE");
                }
            }
        });

        Access_Fine_location_Permission.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://myappurl.netlify.app/");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request)
            {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkMyPermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FINE PERMISSION GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

            }
        }).check();

        Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "COARSE PERMISSION GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

            }
        }).check();
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

//    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions)
//    {
//        if( context != null && permissions != null )
//        {
//            for (String permission : permissions)
//            {
//                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
//                {
//                    return false;
//                }
//            }
//        }
//        return true;
//    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the `AndroidManifest.xml` code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webviewtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WebviewTest">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="my gmaps api key" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is the `build.gradle`

```
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.webviewtest"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
}
```

Kindly help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, have you found a solution? I am facing this problem too. I don't know what is wrong with webview.

Comment: @EdangJeorlie Yeah now it's working for me. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.file_upload;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;
    private DBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        assert webView != null;
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

        webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(500*1024*1024);
        webSettings.setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        if( !isNetworkAvailable() )
        {
            webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        webView.loadUrl("https://gleeful-druid-15e4b7.netlify.app/");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request)
            {
                if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP )
                {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback){
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }

            //For Android 3.0+
//            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
//                mUM = uploadMsg;
//                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
//                i.setType("*/*");
//                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FCR);
//            }
            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
//            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType){
//                mUM = uploadMsg;
//                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
//                i.setType("*/*");
//                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
//                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
//                        FCR);
//            }
            //For Android 4.1+
//            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
//                mUM = uploadMsg;
//                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
//                i.setType("*/*");
//                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
//            }
            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if(photoFile != null){
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    }else{
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null){
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                }else{
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ( ConnectivityManager ) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) ;
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();

    }

    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if( webView.canGoBack() )
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c){
            this.mContext=c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String jsonData)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                String name = data.getString("name");
                String email = data.getString("email");
                long contact_number1 = data.getLong("contact_number1");
                long contact_number2 = data.getLong("contact_number2");
                long retail_size = data.getLong("retail_size");
                String it_automation = data.getString("it_automation");
                long no_of_mobile = data.getLong("no_of_mobile");
                long no_of_tab = data.getLong("no_of_tab");
                long no_of_computer = data.getLong("no_of_computer");
                long no_of_printer = data.getLong("no_of_printer");
                long no_of_scanner = data.getLong("no_of_scanner");
                double latitude = data.getDouble("latitude");
                double longitude = data.getDouble("longitude");
                String image = data.getString("image");

                Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(latitude)  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                dbHandler = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);

                dbHandler.AddRetailData(name, email, contact_number1, contact_number2, retail_size, it_automation, no_of_mobile, no_of_tab, no_of_computer, no_of_printer, no_of_scanner, latitude, longitude, image );

//                Log.d("EMAIL", "value: " + email);
//                Log.d("contact number1", "value: " + contact_number1);
               // Toast.makeText(mContext, email , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(latitude)  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Retail Data has been saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the AndroidManifest.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.file_upload">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.File_Upload">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This worked for me.